# Restricting an app to only use Wifi not mobile data

Tags: mobile-data

I would like to restrict my web-browser (firefox) to only work when on Wifi,
while still allowing all other apps like Google Maps, Google Calendar etc, and even my alternate browser (Brave), to work using mobile data.

Comment: Use a firewall app. See a list here: https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Apps > FireFox > Mobile Data > Turn on "Disable mobile data"

[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] and mention the device model and the Android version? Google Pixel 3a on Android 12 and Samsung Galaxy M12 on Android 13 don't have this option.

Comment: I also do not see this option on Google Pixel 6,  Android 13